# How to add whitespace and make a united looking in WebStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

For example, usually WebStorm will not add extra whitespace to the element, if I want to make it look nice, I have to add extra whitespace for every element I created.

I tried to google it but all I find is "deleting extra whitespace" kind of question and answers. Maybe it is because I don't know how to describe the question. And Google won't accept the image which can let me explain the question more clearly. I can't do anything. Need help with this.

Screenshot 1:

[image]

Screenshot 2:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to **Settings > Code Style > HTML** (*ctrl + alt + S*) and check **Wrap text** and **After tag name**. However this wil add a space to all HTML, not just the self closing ones. `<head>` will become `<head >`. **In empty tag** will do that for you.

[image]

Comment: Cool, just FYI left of the answer you can upvote or accept an answer. That is better than commenting because 1) Other people recognize the best answer that way and 2) You play along with the gamification of SO.

Comment: Actually, I have a small question. After setting the wrapping style, do we need to activate the style manually? Or the project will automatically change the style for me? The reason why I ask this is, I set the PHP array to have a $arr = [ "1" , "2" , "3" ]; with space around "=" and space around each element of the array. but when I type $arr=["1","2","3"]; and press enter, I just switch to the next line, but there is nothing changed. So I am wondering if there is a shortcut key for me to press when I finish a line to wrap the line?

Comment: You have to do it manually: Select code **Code > Reformat Code** or `ctrl + alt + L`